# Is there any way to get a random item without naming every item in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just wanted to know if there is a way to get a random item without hundreds of commands.

Comment: Your loot table file is at https://pastebin.com/ne2By8ei sorry for the wait.  If you need help with installing it, I'm here to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use datapacks, then the following method is a possibility.  The method can take a lot of time to make, but requires a few commands to run.  So in a datapack make a loot table with every item as a possibility.  You can use misode.github.io as a generator.  This loot table doesn't need to be a specific type of loot table, but if you want to get the item in a chest, I'm pretty you have to set it to a chest type.  With a loot table you can add weight to make one item appear more often the others.  If you don't want to spend the time creating this loot table , then if you know a programming language, you can automate it with an executable or a script.  I know a programming language, so if you want me to automate it for you, I can.  After you finished your loot table and properly installed it, then you have a few options.  1: Give a player a container with the item in it.  2: Give a player the item itself to the player.  3: Drop the item on the ground so the player can pick it up.  I will start with number 1.  For this method, use the command
`give <player selector> chest{BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"<your loot table>"}}`

Next is number 2.  For this method use the following command.

`loot give <player selector> loot <your loot table>`

The next and final method is number 3.  For this method use the following command.

`loot spawn <coordinates> loot <your loot table>`

For filling up the spots I didn't put in, use the in game command line.  If you need help with anything let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me. Can you automate it for me?

Comment: @JamesRead I will automate it for you sometime later.  You're welcome.

Comment: @JamesRead What version are you in?  Are you in 1.16.4?

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by “automate it with a programming language”? Do you just mean quick whip up an EXE to write the loot table file? or something to interact with the game, because that would require mods.

Comment: @randomuser922 I'm in 1.16.4

Comment: @Penguin I mean an executable/script.  So programming languages like C, Python, orJavaScript.

Comment: @randomuser922 ... JavaScript can’t be made into an EXE. You may be referring to TypeScript

Comment: @Penguin I know JavaScript can't be made into a executable.  I said "an executable/script" and JavaScript uses scripts and not executables.  So any scripting language will work and any compiled language will work. Ones with things that can modify strings if that makes sense.